# How do I replace a part of a line in a text file with user input?

Tags: c#

Here's the code.

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string textBoxText = TextBox.Text;

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\Bioshock2SP.ini");

    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
        if (line.Contains("VoVolume="))
        {
            //This is where I get confused.
            string settingLine = line;
            string replaceline = (line.Replace(line, textBoxText));
            File.WriteAllText(@"F:\Bioshock2SP.ini", settingLine);
        }
        break;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Setting saved!");
}
```

The idea is to replace part of a setting in a Settings.ini file for a game I play, using the user input of a textbox in my form. The user types in a number for example, "1.56" and then hit the Save button to replace the existing line with their input. In this case that setting is the volume.

The application runs completely fine, but after hitting save and going into the settings file my input isn't saved.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code? Have you confirmed that the code in the loop executes at all?

Comment: Someone edited out the first part of the question, but I'm new to C# I know the basics and a little bit more and that's about it. I really don't know how to use Visual Studio very well, I'll figure out how to do that and let you know, sorry.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `string settingLine = line;`, and run to the breakpoint. My bet is that it never stops there because your `line.Contains` never returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a change in the way you save the file.
Save each line of the file as you get it, editing if required.

```
void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBoxText = TextBox.Text;

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\Bioshock2SP.ini");

    using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"F:\Bioshock2SP.ini"))
    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
        if (line.Contains("VoVolume="))
            file.WriteLine(line.Substring(0, 9) + textBoxText); // Writes something like 'VoVolume=1.56'
        else file.WriteLine(line); // No editing required
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Setting saved!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple of separate issues with your code:

1. Replace Function

   ```
   string replaceline = (line.Replace(line, textBoxText));
   ```

   Replace accepts a string to look for and a string to replace it with.  Your first argument is 'line', so it would replace the whole line with the value in `textBoxText`.  I assume you only want to replace a portion of the line with that value.  In that case, you need to use something like `line.Replace(searchString, textBoxText)` where you have previously defined searchString as the text you want to replace.  If you don't know what that value is, but there is a pattern, you might want to look into using [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) which will let you define a pattern to search and replace.
2. WriteAllText Function

   ```
   File.WriteAllText(@"F:\Bioshock2SP.ini", settingLine);
   ```

   This line will replace the entire contents of BioShock2SP.ini with the value in settingLine.  There are two problems here.

   1. One is that `settingLine` was the saved value before you did the replacement - so it has not included the results of your replace operation.  You should use `replaceline` (assuming it has been correctly modified).
   2. Even if you do that, though, the other is that File.WriteAllText will replace the *whole* file with the value in `settingLine` - which is probably not what you want.  You'd be better off modifying the line in the array and using `File.WriteAllLines` to re-output the whole array - assuming the file has multiple lines in it.

The hints above may help you resolve this - to properly answer the question though, I'd need to see a sample of what the file looks like, and the patterns you are trying to replace.